# Converting character offsets into byte offsets (in Python)

Tags: python, offset, unicode-string

Suppose I have a bunch of files in UTF-8 that I send to an external API in unicode. The API operates on each unicode string and returns a list with `(character_offset, substr)` tuples.

The output I need is the begin and end byte offset for each found substring. If I'm lucky the input text contains only ASCII characters (making character offset and byte offset identical), but this is not always the case. How can I find the begin and end byte offsets for a known begin character offset and substring?

I've answered this question myself, but look forward to other solutions to this problem that are more robust, more efficient, and/or more readable.

Answer (score 5):

I'd solve this using a dictionary mapping character offsets to byte offsets and then looking up the offsets in that.

```
def get_char_to_byte_map(unicode_string):
    """
    Generates a dictionary mapping character offsets to byte offsets for unicode_string.
    """
    response = {}
    byte_offset = 0
    for char_offset, character in enumerate(unicode_string):
        response[char_offset] = byte_offset
        byte_offset += len(character.encode('utf-8'))
    return response

char_to_byte_map = get_char_to_byte_map(text)

for begin_offset, substring in api_response:
    begin_offset = char_to_byte_map[character_offset]
    end_offset = char_to_byte_map[character_offset + len(substring)]
    # do something
```

Performance of this solution as compared to yours depends a lot on the size of the input and the amount of substrings involved. Local micro-benchmarking suggests that encoding each individual character in a text takes about 1000 times as long as encoding the entire text at once.

Comment: Nice solution! So, this will be faster when there is a large amount of substrings. The difference you've found in micro-benchmarking is surprisingly high, though. I'll see if I can check the runtime on some of the strings I'm processing.

Comment: I expect the difference to come from function call overhead. I tested on a string with a length of about 1000000 (one million) characters. That makes it one million function calls vs one function call.

Answer (score 1):

To convert character offsets to byte offsets when needed, I `encode('utf8')` the text leading up to the found substring if there are any non-ASCII characters in the input text, and take its length as begin offset.

```
# Check if text contains non-ASCII characters
needs_offset_conversion = len(text) != len(text.encode('utf8'))

def get_byte_offsets(text, character_offset, substr, needs_conversion):
    if needs_conversion:
        begin_offset = len(text[:character_offset].encode('utf8'))
        end_offset = begin_offset + len(substr.encode('utf8'))
    else:
        begin_offset = character_offset
        end_offset = character_offset + len(substr)
    return begin_offset, end_offset
```

This implementation works, but it encodes a (large) part of the text for each found substring.